# Doubt on Prasolov's notation: $A=||a_{ij}||_1^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm reading Prasolov's: *Problems and Theorems in Linear Algebra*.

He defines the following notation:

$||a_{ij}||_p^n$ as a notation for a matrix, where $p\leq i, \;j\leq n$.

And there is a problem:

$1.1$ Let $A=||a_{ij}||_1^n$ be skew-symmetric and let $n$ be odd. Prove that $|A|=0$.

I guess I can solve the exercise but I'm extremely confused about the notation. Fix an odd $n$, is he talking about all the matrices with $1\leq i, \;j\leq n$? If so, why pick an odd $n$, say $13$, we have: $A=||a_{ij}||_1^{13}$, that is: We are going to prove it to $n=12$ too and hence the selection of an odd $n$ would be useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A = \|a_{ij}\|_{1}^n$ refers specifically to a matrix with $n$ rows and $n$ columns.  In particular, for each $i$ and $j$ satisfying $1 \leq i,j \leq n$, the entry $a_{ij}$ is the entry in the $i$th row and $j$ column.

So, no: proving the statement for $n=13$ does not imply the statement for $n = 12$.

Comment: I know it does not imply. But I thought that he wanted a proof of statements for $n=13$ and all $n\leq 13$.

Comment: All I can say is that this is not what he is saying, and that I don't see what led you  to interpret the question this way.

Comment: I know that the determinant works in a square matrix. But why did he chose this notation instead of just saying "square matrix of order n" or something similar?

Comment: There's no accounting for taste I suppose

Comment: I understood it in the day you answered (but forgot to say). It is a matrix and the $a_{ij}$ is only a mention of the elements inside the matrix. I was understanding something **completely** different.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out, at any rate